# Store same reference item multiple times in array, will one change affect them all?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I am getting some weird running times for my mergesort algorithm...I want to run the algorithm (say 1000 times) on the same permuted ArrayList. Right now, I just create an array of ArrayList of size 1000, then time how long it takes to sort each of these, then take the average of the times.

So my question is: am I sorting the same list over and over? If I change one instance of the ArrayList in the array say at index 0, will the other ArrayLists in the array stay the same? I would assume so, but I want to be certain that's not happening? Thanks.

```
    for (int N = 1000; N <= 10000; N += 1000) {

      //copy the array
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      ArrayList<Integer>[] container = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[N];
      ArrayList<Integer> testArray1 = generatePermutedOrder(N);
      for(int j=0; j<timesToLoop; j++){
        container[j] = testArray1;
      }

      System.out.print(N + "\t");

      // let things stabilize
      startTime = System.nanoTime();
      while (System.nanoTime() - startTime < 1000000000)
        ;

      // time the routine
      startTime = System.nanoTime();
      for (int i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++) {
          mergesort(container[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Yes if you are using the same ArrayList object (one `new ArrayList()`) then all operations will be done on the same object. Fortunately taking a copy is simple - constructor / addAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change one instance of the ArrayList in the array say at index 0, will the other ArrayLists in the array stay the same?

Yes, modifying ArrayList at index 0 won't effect the other indexes. (but make sure that other indexes don't have reference to same ArrayList)

Scenerio 1: (Modifying index 0 will effect index 1)

```
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

arr[0] = aList;
arr[1] = aList;
```

Scenerio 2: (Modifying index 0 will NOT effect index 1)

```
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
ArrayList aList1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList aList2 = new ArrayList();

arr[0] = aList1;
arr[1] = aList2;
```

So, make sure it's Scenerio 2 in your code.

EDIT:

```
ArrayList<Integer> testArray1 = generatePermutedOrder(N);       
for(int j=0; j<timesToLoop; j++)
{         
    container[j] = testArray1; // same reference pointing to same ArrayList is added in each interation
}
```

You are adding same reference to each index. So, modifying at any index will effect remaining indexes.

Comment: Yeah, I think I might have a problem then? How do I efficiently perform case 2 without declaring 1000 different ArrayLists (obviously can't do that by hand)?

Comment: if the contents of `ArrayList` are same, why do you want to `mergesort` it again and again?

Comment: I want to run it multiple times so that I can get an average time. Just running it once isn't necessarily representative of the average case? Nevertheless, that's what my professor said I needed to do...

Comment: so, don't create so many `ArrayList` at the start. in each interation, copy the original to a new one, and pass to `mergesort`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the other `ArrayList` will stay the same.
For example.

```
array[0].set(0,object)
```

Will not affect the `ArrayList` at `array[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You said you created an array of ArrayLists, but what did you assign into each slot in that array?  Did you create one ArrayList instance and assign it to all 1000 slots in the array, or did you create 1000 different ArrayLists (e.g. using `new` in a loop) and assign a different one to each array slot?

If you store multiple references to the same object in multiple places, changes to that object will be visible through all the references.

Answer (score 0):

If you just create an array of ArrayList objects they're all null.  If you then iterate through the array and instantiate each ArrayList with new, then they're all different (each call to new ArrayList() will create a new one).

It's possible to put the same ArrayList reference in every element of the array by creating an ArrayList and then iterating through the array and assigning every element of the array the value of the (already created) ArrayList.  This is probably not what you want to do.